# Tridion Docs 2013 SP2 | Unable to unpublish the publication from the Broker

Tags: publishing, tridion-docs, unpublishing

I am trying to unpublish the publication in Tridion docs 2013 SP2. The publication status is **Released or Draft**. When I try unpublish the publication it shows below Error

[image]

After this Error the Status changes to **Unpublish Pending**. If I try to cancel the process, It shows me -

> FISHUNPUBLISHEVENTID  The FieldValue "FISHUNPUBLISHEVENTID" cannot be
>   returned, because it is not initialized.

I tried to check the logs which looks like -

> 11:24:29.6064 Warn    12  00024   a:UC:Admin  /ISHCM/EventMonitor/Main/DetailsViaEventId?eventId=&detailsTitle=Sensation+Beats+Audio-v1-DynamicDelivery-en    Trisoft.Utilities.ServiceReferences.Helpers.ServicePointManagerHelper.OptimizeServicePointManagerDefaultConnectionLimit asp.net detected. Bypassing []
>   11:24:29.6230   Error   12  00024   a:UC:Admin  /ISHCM/EventMonitor/Main/DetailsViaEventId?eventId=&detailsTitle=Sensation+Beats+Audio-v1-DynamicDelivery-en    Trisoft.InfoShare.EventMonitor.Services.EventMonitorService.GetProgressItem     []
>   System.ArgumentException: Invalid event id.
>      at Trisoft.InfoShare.Client.Remote.Asmx.EventMonitorService25.GetProgressId(String eventId)
>      at Trisoft.InfoShare.Client.Remote.EventMonitorService.Trisoft.InfoShare.Client.Services.IEventMonitorService.GetProgressId(String eventId)
>      at Trisoft.InfoShare.EventMonitor.Services.EventMonitorService.GetProgressItem(String eventId, IList'1 requestedFields)
>   MainController.GetProgressItem => EventMonitorService.Trisoft.InfoShare.EventMonitor.Services.IEventMonitorService.GetProgressItem => EventMonitorService.GetProgressItem
>   11:24:29.6230   Error   12  00024   a:UC:Admin  /ISHCM/EventMonitor/Main/DetailsViaEventId?eventId=&detailsTitle=Sensation+Beats+Audio-v1-DynamicDelivery-en    Trisoft.InfoShare.EventMonitor.Services.EventMonitorService.GetProgressItem (eventId=[],requestedFields=[null]) []
>   11:24:29.6230   Error   12  00024   a:UC:Admin  /ISHCM/EventMonitor/Main/DetailsViaEventId?eventId=&detailsTitle=Sensation+Beats+Audio-v1-DynamicDelivery-en    Trisoft.InfoShare.Web.FilterAttributes.TrisoftHandleErrorAndLogAttribute.OnException        []
>   System.ArgumentException: Invalid event id.
>      at Trisoft.InfoShare.Client.Remote.Asmx.EventMonitorService25.GetProgressId(String eventId)
>      at Trisoft.InfoShare.Client.Remote.EventMonitorService.Trisoft.InfoShare.Client.Services.IEventMonitorService.GetProgressId(String eventId)
>      at Trisoft.InfoShare.EventMonitor.Services.EventMonitorService.GetProgressItem(String eventId, IList'1 requestedFields)
>      at Trisoft.InfoShare.EventMonitor.Services.EventMonitorService.Trisoft.InfoShare.EventMonitor.Services.IEventMonitorService.GetProgressItem(String eventId, IList'1 requestedFields)
>      at Trisoft.InfoShare.Web.Areas.EventMonitor.Controllers.MainController.GetProgressItem(String eventId, ActionResult& actionResult)
>      at Trisoft.InfoShare.Web.Areas.EventMonitor.Controllers.MainController.DetailsViaEventId(String eventId, String detailsTitle)
>      at lambda_method(Closure , ControllerBase , Object[] )
>      at System.Web.Mvc.ActionMethodDispatcher.Execute(ControllerBase controller, Object[] parameters)
>      at System.Web.Mvc.ReflectedActionDescriptor.Execute(ControllerContext controllerContext, IDictionary'2 parameters)
>      at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionMethod(ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionDescriptor actionDescriptor, IDictionary'2 parameters)
>      at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.b__39(IAsyncResult asyncResult, ActionInvocation innerInvokeState)
>      at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.WrappedAsyncResult'2.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
>      at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.WrappedAsyncResultBase'1.End()
>      at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.EndInvokeActionMethod(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
>      at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.AsyncInvocationWithFilters.b__3d()
>      at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.AsyncInvocationWithFilters.<>c__DisplayClass46.b__3f()
>      at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.AsyncInvocationWithFilters.<>c__DisplayClass46.b__3f()
>      at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.<>c__DisplayClass33.b__32(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
>      at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.WrappedAsyncResult'1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
>      at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.WrappedAsyncResultBase'1.End()
>      at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.EndInvokeActionMethodWithFilters(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
>      at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.<>c__DisplayClass21.<>c__DisplayClass2b.b__1c()
>      at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.<>c__DisplayClass21.b__1e(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
>   <>c__DisplayClass21.b__1e => ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeExceptionFilters => TrisoftHandleErrorAndLogAttribute.OnException
>   11:24:29.6230   Error   12  00024   a:UC:Admin  /ISHCM/EventMonitor/Main/DetailsViaEventId?eventId=&detailsTitle=Sensation+Beats+Audio-v1-DynamicDelivery-en    Trisoft.InfoShare.Web.FilterAttributes.TrisoftHandleErrorAndLogAttribute.OnException    (controller=[Main],action=[DetailsViaEventId])  []
>   11:24:29.9629   Info    10  00000   na::        Trisoft.Web.HttpApplication.Dispose Disposing web application.  []
>   11:24:29.9629   Info    10  00000   na::        Trisoft.Utilities.Common.Modules.RemoveVersionHttpResponseHeaderModule.Dispose  Trisoft.Utilities.Common.Modules.RemoveVersionHttpResponseHeaderModule (with hashcode 40644060) is disposed.    []
>   11:24:30.5274   Info    11  00000   na::        Trisoft.Utilities.Logging.Helpers.RequestIDHelper.Set   (requestID=[25])    []
>   11:24:30.5274   Info    13  00000   na::        Trisoft.Utilities.Logging.Helpers.RequestIDHelper.Set   (requestID=[26])    []
>   11:24:30.5283   Info    12  00000   na::        Trisoft.Utilities.Common.Modules.RemoveVersionHttpResponseHeaderModule.Init

It looks I am missing some configuration somewhere.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It was due to unpublish plugin was missing from *XML Write Plug-in Settings* xml. I have added below information tags in this file in the Tridion Docs CMS.

> ```
>     <plugin name="ISHRAISEDITADELIVERYUNPUBLISHEVENT" handler="RaiseUnpublishEvent" ishcondition="ISHLevel='lng' and ISHOutputFormat.FDITAOTTRANSTYPE='ishditadelivery' and CurrentAction='SetMetadata'">
>       <description>Starts a background task when the 'FISHPUBSTATUS' field is changed to 'Unpublish pending'</description>
>       <workingset>
>         <ishfields>
>           <ishfield name="FISHPUBSTATUS" level="lng" />
>           <ishfield name="FISHPUBISDEPLOYED" level="lng" />
>           <ishfield name="FISHUNPUBLISHEVENTID" level="lng" />
>         </ishfields>
>       </workingset>
>       <initialize>
>         <parameters>
>           <parameter name="EventTypeConfiguration">
>             <configuration>
>               <eventtype>DITADELIVERYUNPUBLISH</eventtype>
>             </configuration>
>           </parameter>
>         </parameters>
>       </initialize>
>     </plugin>
> ```

Answer (score 0):

OOTB SDL Tridion Docs 13 SP2 - Installation this configuration should be configured by default.

In case if you did not receive a fully prepared database dump-backup file or upgrading from the previous version it needs to be done. otherwise, this is done and configured.

The SDL documentation indeed! it's mentioned this needs to be done part of Post-installation tasks -[Completing the Administrator setup](https://docs.sdl.com/LiveContent/content/en-US/SDL%20Tridion%20Docs-v1.1.2/GUID-6A1DEC0B-9D25-41CB-A424-811EB28A18D2)

Comment: Thank you Velmurugan for adding your comments here and make me aware. I was working on a preinstalled instance and I was not familiar with that.